# Adding services after container has been built

Tags: ioc-container, autofac

Is it possible to register a service at run-time, meaning after the `ContainerBuilder` has been built and the `Container` has been created (and `ContainerBuilder` disposed of)?

Comment: Currently, best practices say AutoFac containers [are immutable](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/best-practices/index.html#consider-a-container-as-immutable)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Yes you can, using the `Update` method on `ContainerBuilder`:

```
var newBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
newBuilder.Register...;

newBuilder.Update(existingContainer);
```

Comment: Do note that updating an existing container that has already been used to resolve can result in undeterministic behavior. For instance, replacing components that are dependencies of already resolved singletons cause the original component to stay referenced.

Comment: Update is being deprecated https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/811.

Comment: Yes, it is obsolete, and I came here to find the alternate option

Answer (score 30):

Since ContainerBuilder.Update has been deprecated, the new recommendation is to use child lifetime scope.

**Adding Registrations to a Lifetime Scope**

Autofac allows you to add registrations “on the fly” as you create lifetime scopes. This can help you when you need to do a sort of “spot weld” limited registration override or if you generally just need some additional stuff in a scope that you don’t want to register globally. You do this by passing a lambda to BeginLifetimeScope() that takes a ContainerBuilder and adds registrations.

```
using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(
  builder =>
  {
    builder.RegisterType<Override>().As<IService>();
    builder.RegisterModule<MyModule>();
  }))
{
  // The additional registrations will be available
  // only in this lifetime scope.
}
```

[Working with Lifetime Scopes](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html)

Comment: The thing to note is that comment in the using block. "The additional registrations will be available only in this lifetime scope."