# ASP.NET Core with existing IoC container & environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'd like to run the *ASP.NET Core* web stack along with *MVC* within a Windows service environment which already hosts an existing application in order to provide a frontend for it. The application uses Autofac for DI concerns which is nice because it already has an extension for `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` (on which ASP.NET Core heavily relies upon).

Now, my problem is: ASP.NET Core wants to register its own services within the IoC container, at a stage where my own container has already been built. The only way I can see to run my own 'application part' along with ASP.NET Core is by setting up my application within the scope of the ASP.NET Core web host `Startup` class, what appears to make ASP.NET Core behaving like a full blown application framework rather than web framework. What I also tried is dropping the Startup completely and setting the web host up like this:

```
        var containerBuilder    = new ContainerBuilder();
        var container           = containerBuilder.Build();
        var webHost             = new WebHostBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddMvc();
            })
            .Configure(app =>
            {
                app.ApplicationServices = new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseMvc();
            })
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .Build();

        webHost.Run();
```

However this doesn't work because ASP.NET Core seems to override all configurations as soon as the web host is getting built. So, is there a way to integrate *ASP.NET Core* as well as *MVC* in an existing environment rather than the other way around? Maybe by setting it up manually rather than using `WebHostBuilder` etc.?

Comment: Simply, don't build your container before the `Startup.Configure` method is being called. In the Configure method you get a `IServiceCollection` passed in. There you register all your services and ASP.NET Core dependencies using the `services.AddXxx(...)` methods. Then you pass this to autofac: `containerBuilder.Populate(services)` to register them within Autofac, then build the container, and return it in the `Configure` method as seen in the documentation here: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html

Comment: @Tseng you should write that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @Tseng Yes, I am aware of how it's supposed to be done, but that simply ignores the fact that the ASP.NET Core web application is not the composition root of my app, I just want to start the web framework as an extension, working with an existing container which has been created previously.

Comment: You can also update an already built container, but check the comment on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5009312/455493. It says, it can result in indeterministic behavior if services were already resolved by the existing container.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found is using Update() function of Autofac container. But Autofac lib marks this approach as [bad practice](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/best-practices/).

Outside of Startup class:

```
class Program {
   public static IContainer Container { get; private set; }
   
   void Main(){
      var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
      ...
      Container = builder.Build();
   }
}
```

And in Startup class:

```
 public abstract class Startup
 {
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
       builder.Populate(services);
       // Update existing container
       builder.Update(Program.Container);
    }
 }
```

**For sure its a bad hack + I suggest to avoid this approach.**

But the answer

> don't build your container before the Startup.Configure

is not always applicable. In my case I used Azure Service Fabric .Net Core WebAPI stateless service and suggestion to build container inside Startup is wrong since I need to inject StatelessService before Startup runs.