# Update autofac container from IHostedService asynchronously on app startup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, autofac

I am having an ASP.net core 3.0 app and I want to see if I can register some of my Orleans Cluster Clients asynchronously on app startup, due to the fact the creation and making the connections to Orleans Cluster are heavy. According to this [article](https://andrewlock.net/running-async-tasks-on-app-startup-in-asp-net-core-3/) I created my own IHostedService, but when I implemented startAsync method I am not sure how to get the autofac container which I am using in Startup.cs and update it with my clients registrations. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998870/adding-services-after-container-has-been-built) but see my below code, still I don't see the clients are getting registered. Is it doable or am I missing anything here? thanks!

```
Startup.cs

...
public static IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var coreBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    
    // other autofac registrations...

    services.AddHostedService<MyService>();
    coreBuilder.populate(services);

    var container = coreBuilder.Build();

    var serviceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
    return serviceProvider;
}
```

```
MyService.cs

public MyService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public MyService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // get the autofac container from Startup.cs and update with cluster client registrations? 
        using(var scope = this._serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILifeTimeScope>()
.BeginLifeTimeScope(builder => do registration here...)) {}
    }

    // noop
    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** update the DI container on-the-fly like that. Once it's built, it's built.

You have another option: make a factory class that caches the clients, initialize them in the background, then retrieve them from the factory.

```cs
class MyService
{
    // ...   
}

class MyServiceFactory
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyService> _instances = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyService>();

    public async Task<MyService> CreateAsync(string key)
    {
        if (_instances.TryGetValue(key, out var service))
        {
            return service;
        }

        // perform expensive initialization
        // ...
        service = new MyService();

        _instances[key] = service;
        return service;
    }
}

class MyServiceInitializer: BackgroundService
{
    private MyServiceFactory _serviceFactory;

    public MyServiceInitializer(MyServiceFactory serviceFactory)
    {
        _serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await _serviceFactory.CreateAsync("first instance");
        await _serviceFactory.CreateAsync("second instance");
    }
}
```

Register the factory as singleton, (or make `Instances` a `static` property).

```cs
services.AddSingleton<MyServiceFactory>();
services.AddHostedService<MyServiceInitializer>();
```

Then resolve an instance you need. It will resolve instantly, because it's been initialized in the background.

```cs
class MyController
{
    private MyServiceFactory _serviceFactory;

    public MyController(MyServiceFactory serviceFactory)
    {
        _serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var service = await _serviceFactory.CreateAsync("first instance");
        // use the service
    }
}
```